# RESTful PUT if not exists?

Tags: http, rest, put

Let's say I'm creating a RESTful interface, and I want to upload a resource using `PUT` to `/resources/{id}`. But I only want to be upload the thing if it hasn't been uploaded before.

I realize that `PUT` should be idempotent, so if I `PUT` something twice to the same URL it should succeed both times, right?

I also understand that I could use `HEAD` on an existing resource, and then [use an `ETag`](http://blog.m.artins.net/restful-web-services-preventing-race-conditions/) to in my `PUT` to ensure that the resource hasn't been modified since I last checked.

But how can I ensure that I only upload a thing if the thing doesn't already exist? That is, how can I make sure I don't step on someone else's thing?

Answer (score 5):

> I realize that PUT should be idempotent, so if I PUT something twice
> to the same URL it should succeed both times right?

Correct.

> But how can I ensure that I only upload a thing if the thing doesn't
> already exist? That is, how can I make sure I don't step on someone
> else's thing?

Don't use a HEAD call. Make a PUT call using the header `If-None-Match: *`. This will instruct the server to only perform the operation if no current entity exists, as detailed in [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.26) paragraph 3.

Answer (score 4):

See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7232.html#rfc.section.3.2.p.7:

"If-None-Match can also be used with a value of "*" to prevent an unsafe request method (e.g., PUT) from inadvertently modifying an existing representation of the target resource when the client believes that the resource does not have a current representation (Section 4.2.1 of [RFC7231]). This is a variation on the "lost update" problem that might arise if more than one client attempts to create an initial representation for the target resource."